# Text being unresponsive. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am Currently having trouble making my website responsive. To explain clearly the problem, Currently, the website is following the width of the tab, however, the problem arises that the text does not follow along and it overlays the images placed in the boxes.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;600&display=swap");
*{
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
    background: #1b1b1b;
}
nav:after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
nav .logo{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: cyan;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color: cyan;
    box-shadow: none;
}
nav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: top .3s;
}
.background{
    background-color: #212529;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    left: -30%;   
}
.overlay h3{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: crimson;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.overlay p{
    font-size: 35px;
}
.main h1{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.text{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    white-space: initial;
    margin: 0 auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.section{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.section img{
    height: 250px;
}
.section h1{
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: black;
}
.section p{
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 55%;
    height: 50px;
    white-space: initial;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.section2{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: right;
}
.section2 img{
    height: 250px;
}
.section2 h1{
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: black;
}
.section2 p{
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 55%;
    height: 50px;
    white-space: initial;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.section2 sup{
    font-size: 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.section3{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.section3 img{
    height: 250px;
}
.section3 h1{
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: black;
}
.section3 sup{
    font-size: 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.section3 p{
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 55%;
    height: 50px;
    white-space: initial;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.section4{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: right;
}
.section4 img{
    height: 250px;
}
.section4 h1{
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: black;
}
.section4 p{
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 55%;
    height: 50px;
    white-space: initial;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}


.footer{
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 40px;
    clear: both;
}
.footer .social{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    color:#4b4c4d;
}
.footer .social a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #424242;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.footer .social a:hover{
    color:#24262b;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.footer ul{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer ul li a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.footer ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.footer .copyright{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSSFolder/Class2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">Revolutionary Fitness</div>
        <ul>
            <div class="items">
                <li><a href="HomePage.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="background">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h3>Classes</h3>
            <p>Insert Something Here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>Classes, coaches and community</h1>
        <div class="text">
            <p>At Virgin Active, we do health and fitness differently.
                We have expertly crafted exercise experiences that are the perfect blend of intelligent programming and feel-good movement.
                We've got everything from Yoga to HIIT, so you can move your body any way you want.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <img src="../ImageFolder/Yoga.jpg" alt="Yoga">
        <div class="ClassText">
            <h1>Yoga</h1>
            <p>
                Choose from Classes with dynamism,energy and athleticism, to an authentic and peaceful experience.
                <br><br>
                Classes include: Align,Flow,Calm,SkyPark Yoga
                <br><br>
                <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
            </p>     
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="section2">
        <div class="ClassText">
            <h1>Cycle</h1>
            <p>
                Custom designed bikes, choreographed lighting and fresh daily beats to inspire you for every ride
                <br><br>
                Classes include: Cycle Spirit, Cycle Burn, RPM<sup>TM</sup>, THE TRIP<sup>TM</sup>
                <br><br>
                <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <img src="../ImageFolder/Cycle.jpg" alt="Cycle">
    </div>

    <div class="section3">
        <img src="../ImageFolder/Les.jpg" alt="Les">
        <div class="ClassText">
            <h1>Les Mils<sup>TM</sup></h1>
            <p>
                Mixing the hottest music with cutting edge-exercise science, motivation and the
                energy of many, Les Mills<sup>TM</sup> group fitness classes make you fall in love with fitness
                Discover our range of world-class group fitness workouts below.
                <br><br>
                Classes include: BodyPump<sup>TM</sup>,BodyCombat<sup>TM</sup>,THETRIP<sup>TM</sup>
                <br><br>
                <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="section4">
        <div class="ClassText">
            <h1>Reformer Pilates</h1>
            <p>
                Hundreds of Reformer classes on offer from morning to night.
                <br><br>
                Classes include: Beginner,Intermediate
                <br><br>
                <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <img src="../ImageFolder/Reformer.jpg" alt="Reformer">
    </div>


    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="social">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="copyright">
            <small>&copy;2022 Revolutionary Fitness</small>
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is because you explicitly set `left: -30%`

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexbox` in `.background` also remove `left` & `width` from `.overlay`.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;600&display=swap");
* {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background: #1b1b1b;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

nav .logo {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: cyan;
  box-shadow: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: top .3s;
}

.background {
  background-color: #212529;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  
  /* USE FLEXBOX */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  
  /* ADD SOME PADDING FOR BETTER UI */
  padding-inline: 16px; /* LEFT and Right */
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay h3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: crimson;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.overlay p {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.main h1 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  white-space: initial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.section {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.section img {
  height: 250px;
}

.section h1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: black;
}

.section p {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: initial;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.section2 img {
  height: 250px;
}

.section2 h1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: black;
}

.section2 p {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: initial;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.section2 sup {
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.section3 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.section3 img {
  height: 250px;
}

.section3 h1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: black;
}

.section3 sup {
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.section3 p {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: initial;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.section4 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.section4 img {
  height: 250px;
}

.section4 h1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: black;
}

.section4 p {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: initial;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 40px;
  clear: both;
}

.footer .social {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  color: #4b4c4d;
}

.footer .social a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #424242;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer .social a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.footer ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer .copyright {
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">Revolutionary Fitness</div>
  <ul>
    <div class="items">
      <li><a href="HomePage.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.php">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="background">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h3>Classes</h3>
    <p>Insert Something Here...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Classes, coaches and community</h1>
  <div class="text">
    <p>At Virgin Active, we do health and fitness differently. We have expertly crafted exercise experiences that are the perfect blend of intelligent programming and feel-good movement. We've got everything from Yoga to HIIT, so you can move your body any
      way you want.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <img src="../ImageFolder/Yoga.jpg" alt="Yoga">
  <div class="ClassText">
    <h1>Yoga</h1>
    <p>
      Choose from Classes with dynamism,energy and athleticism, to an authentic and peaceful experience.
      <br><br> Classes include: Align,Flow,Calm,SkyPark Yoga
      <br><br>
      <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="section2">
  <div class="ClassText">
    <h1>Cycle</h1>
    <p>
      Custom designed bikes, choreographed lighting and fresh daily beats to inspire you for every ride
      <br><br> Classes include: Cycle Spirit, Cycle Burn, RPM<sup>TM</sup>, THE TRIP<sup>TM</sup>
      <br><br>
      <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <img src="../ImageFolder/Cycle.jpg" alt="Cycle">
</div>

<div class="section3">
  <img src="../ImageFolder/Les.jpg" alt="Les">
  <div class="ClassText">
    <h1>Les Mils<sup>TM</sup></h1>
    <p>
      Mixing the hottest music with cutting edge-exercise science, motivation and the energy of many, Les Mills<sup>TM</sup> group fitness classes make you fall in love with fitness Discover our range of world-class group fitness workouts below.
      <br><br> Classes include: BodyPump<sup>TM</sup>,BodyCombat<sup>TM</sup>,THETRIP<sup>TM</sup>
      <br><br>
      <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="section4">
  <div class="ClassText">
    <h1>Reformer Pilates</h1>
    <p>
      Hundreds of Reformer classes on offer from morning to night.
      <br><br> Classes include: Beginner,Intermediate
      <br><br>
      <a href="login.php">Sign Up</a><span> to book this class</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <img src="../ImageFolder/Reformer.jpg" alt="Reformer">
</div>


<footer class="footer">
  <div class="social">
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="copyright">
    <small>&copy;2022 Revolutionary Fitness</small>
  </p>
</footer>
```

P.S - added some padding in `.background`.